# Separator Between Multiple Variables in Django Template (DTL)

Tags: django, django-templates

Given three or more variables in my `DTL` template what is the most convenient way to assure that an interpunct is always between two variables?

```
<div>{{ person.name }} · {{ person.phone }} · {{ person.city }}</div>
```

Expected:

```
<div>John · 1234567 · New York</div>
<!-- {{ person.city }} is null or empty-->
<div>John · 1234567</div>
```

Is there an easy way to solve this with built-in functionality? I try to avoid writing custom `Django` filters/template tags.

Comment: Are you actually using Jinja2, or Django template language?

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Makes sense to me. To be honest I was just hoping that I miss something trivial. Write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this easily in Django template language. Either pass a list of non-empty values from your view, e.g. `["John", "1234567"]`, or write a custom tag or filter so that you can do something like `{% interpunct person.name person.phone person.city %}` or `{{ person|display_person }}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can (ab)use the `cycle` tag for this purpose. Place it in front of each list item, then use it to emit nothing on first pass, then the separator thereafter. Use in a `for` loop is straightforward. Use outside needs this pattern:

```
{% cycle '' '|' '|' '|' as itemsep silent %}
{% if foo %}
{{ itemsep }}{% cycle itemsep %}
Foo!
{% endif %}
{% if bar %}
{{ itemsep }}{% cycle itemsep %}
Bar!
{% endif %}
{% if foobar %}
{{ itemsep }}{% cycle itemsep %}
FooBar!
{% endif %}
```

Or, miss the `silent` complexity by just using an extra `''`

```
{% cycle '' '' '|' '|' '|' as itemsep %}
{% if foo %}
{% cycle itemsep %}
Foo!
{% endif %}
...
```